# Произойдет ли вызов деструкторов при следующем коде?

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

Имеется класс фабрики, который при уничтожении самой фабрики *(она не статическая и может иметь как один так и множество экземпляров)* должен очистить за собой все.

Структура фабрики:

```
struct window;

struct ICEY_WINDOW_SYSTEM_API factory
{
    explicit factory(UINT style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
                     HINSTANCE application_instance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr),
                     HICON icon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION),
                     HCURSOR cursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW),
                     HBRUSH background = HBRUSH(GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH)),
                     const wchar_t* class_name = L"icey::window::system::factory::default_window_class",
                     const wchar_t* menu_name = nullptr);

    virtual ~factory();

    using factory_window_data = std::pair<HWND, std::shared_ptr<window>>;
    using factory_self_data = std::vector<factory_window_data>;
    using factory_data = std::pair<factory*, factory_self_data>;
    using factory_window_list = std::vector<factory_data>;

    const WNDCLASSW& get_window_class() const;

    factory(const factory&) = delete;
    factory(factory&&) = delete;

    factory& operator =(const factory&) = delete;
    factory& operator =(factory&&) = delete;

private:
    WNDCLASSW m_window_class_;
    static factory_window_list m_window_list_;
    static std::shared_ptr<window>& find_by_hwnd(HWND hwnd);
    static LRESULT __stdcall window_procedure(HWND h_wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);
};
```

```
static std::shared_ptr<window> null_ptr_value(nullptr);

LRESULT __stdcall factory::window_procedure(HWND h_wnd, const UINT msg, const WPARAM w_param, const LPARAM l_param)
{
    std::shared_ptr<window> &window = find_by_hwnd(h_wnd);
    return !window ? DefWindowProc(h_wnd, msg, w_param, l_param) : window->window_procedure(h_wnd, msg, w_param, l_param);
}

factory::factory(const UINT style, HINSTANCE application_instance, HICON icon, HCURSOR cursor,
                 HBRUSH background, const wchar_t* class_name, const wchar_t* menu_name):
    m_window_class_
    {
        style,
        window_procedure,
        0,
        0,
        application_instance,
        icon,
        cursor,
        background,
        menu_name,
        class_name
    }
{
    m_window_list_.push_back(factory_data(this, factory_self_data()));
}

factory::~factory()
{
    const factory_window_list::const_iterator it = std::find_if(m_window_list_.begin(), m_window_list_.end(),
                                                                [=](const factory* factory_ptr)-> bool
                                                                {
                                                                    return factory_ptr == this;
                                                                });

    if (m_window_list_.end() != it)
    {
        m_window_list_.erase(it); // ??
    }
}

const WNDCLASSW& factory::get_window_class() const
{
    return m_window_class_;
}

std::shared_ptr<window>& factory::find_by_hwnd(HWND hwnd)
{
    std::shared_ptr<window> ptr(nullptr);

    for (factory_data& factory_data : m_window_list_)
    {
        for (factory_window_data& window_data : factory_data.second)
        {
            if(window_data.first == hwnd)
            {
                return window_data.second;
            }
        }
    }

    return null_ptr_value;
}
```

Интересует факт того, что при удалении из вектора - пары, деструктор станет владельцем этой пары, и как только мы выйдем из деструктора, то все само собой уберется из памяти.

```
m_window_list_.erase(it); // ??
```

Или подскажите как это лучше реализовать, но сохранить функциональность.

Comment: *"при удалении из вектора - пары, деструктор станет владельцем этой пары, и как только мы выйдем из деструктора, то все само собой уберется из памяти"* - чта? При выходе из деструктора будет вызван деструктор для всех полей и базовых объектов этого объекта. Ну и еще в самом деструкторе вручную удаляется один элемент из `m_window_list_`

Comment: Деструктор не может быть владельцем, так как это не объект. Да и почему при очищение списка не использовать cleare? Что касается памяти, то удаление из контейнера не влечет за собой вызова delete

Comment: Но итератор же помечен как `const`, думал что произйдет удаление этого итератора и далее по цепочке...

Comment: Странно, но это работает!

Comment: Когда фабрика умерла. она уничтожила всех своих потомков: `ptr: 012FA2D0, ~window
ptr: 012F5ED8, ~window
ptr: 012FC708, ~window
ptr: 013073D8, ~window
ptr: 01307408, ~window
ptr: 01307498, ~window
ptr: 013074F8, ~window
ptr: 01307438, ~window
ptr: 01307468, ~window
ptr: 01307528, ~window`